# How can you find a substring within a string if some of the characters can be any value?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am trying to find a substring within a given string. However, the substring I am searching for can include special characters, namely '#' and '%'. Whenever '#' is encountered, the value of the character can be any digit, and '%' can be any character (any ascii character). Would it be best to iterate through the substring, search for any characters that come before a '%' or '#' in the main string, then test each character in the main string after that? I am not sure where else to begin.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Regex

Comment: I think you need to look at Python module [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). You can get any specific character by using this module. You can also see examples from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple. Regex is slow and adds a bunch of code.

Test the char values one at a time and exit early if not a match. Check against a match if not a wild card otherwise against a range based on the wild card. # is any char, % is any digit. Appears from your question that the wild cards are in the substring, not target string.

Here's the commented code:

```
#include <string>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

std::optional<size_t> match(const std::string& s_sub, const std::string& s)
{
    if (s.length() < s_sub.length())
        return std::nullopt;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= s.length() - s_sub.length(); i++)
        for (size_t offset = 0; offset < s_sub.length(); offset++)
        {
            // Check for char match or wild cards "#" or "%" (any char or any digit)
            if (s_sub[offset] == '#'
                || (s_sub[offset] == '%' && (s[offset + i] <= 9 || s[offset + i] >= 0))
                || s_sub[offset] == s[offset + i])
            {
                if (offset == s_sub.length() - 1)
                    return i;   // if done and still matched, return position
                else
                    continue;   // Check next char if not done
            }
            else
                break;  // early exit if no match
        }
    return std::nullopt;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<const char*, 2>, 4>  args{ {{"%aa#", "5k7aaxxx"}, {"a", "ba"}, {"g%#h", "r7g4jh"}, {"a", "bcdef"} }};
    for (const auto& set : args)
    {
        auto result = match(set[0], set[1]);
        if (result)
            std::cout << "Substring \"" << set[0] << "\" in \""<< set[1] << "\"" " located at " << result.value() << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Substring \"" << set[0] << "\" in \"" << set[1] << "\"" " not found" << '\n';
    }
}
```

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Eh84d1rfz)